# Do I have to collect my luggage when transiting through Moscow?

Tags: transit, luggage, moscow

After a lot of searching and information I decided to travel from Delhi to Grand Cayman. I am thinking of two separate ticket booking:

1. Delhi (Del) to Moscow(Svo)
   5:10 Am - 9:20 Am Aeroflot.
   Layover 2:40 Hours
2. Moscow(Svo) to Havana(Hav).12:00 Pm - 5:15 Pm Aeroflot.
3. Havana - Gcm after 22 Hours.

I want to Know about the checked in luggage. Will it directly reach Havana or I have to collect it at Moscow airport?

I will not be requiring any visa to transit at Moscow or Havana.

Comment: I believe the luggage will be automatically transferred onto the Havana flight, but your best bet would be to call Aeroflot and ask them.

Comment: Are you travelling on all of the segments under the same ticket?

Comment: No i m not travelling under the same ticket. I have booked 3 Tickets seapratey. First two tickets are of aeroflot and the last one is of cayman airways.

Answer (score 1):

On full-service airlines luggage will almost always, if not always, be checked through to the final destination if all of the sectors are on the same airline or on partners in the same alliance. This should definitely happen if travel is all on the same ticket which is not the case for you.

Some budget airlines do not check through baggage even when the journey is all on their network. Air Asia, for example, only do this on selected "[FLY-THRU](http://www.airasia.com/ask/template.do?id=517)" routes and for an additional fee.

You appear not to have stated who the last flight is with nor if it is that flight which has the seperate ticket. Aeroflot may be willing and able to check your baggage through to Grand Cayman or they may not. If you need to know in advance you will have to ask them. I suspect your baggage will be checked through at least to Moscow but you can ask at the same time to be sure!

Of course at the very least this will all be revealed to you when you check in.

Make sure you leave enough time to pick up your bags and check back if necessary and confirm that you won't have to go through immigration to pick up your bags.

Comment: *On full-service airlines luggage will almost always, if not always, be checked through to the final destination if all of the sectors are on the same airline or on partners in the same alliance* - Not true.  Buy 2 different tickets on the same airline through a connection point and you will have to recheck.

Comment: @Karlson Thanks. I'll edit if need be but do you have a link with more info on this or experience of carriers where that is the case? This article for example seems to be saying that 3 US airlines are stopping inter-airline check through on 2 tickets but not 2 tickets on the same line. I may have misread. http://www.smartertravel.com/blogs/today-in-travel/beware-two-ticket-air-trips.html?id=13119956

Comment: @Karlson More often than not the agent will check your luggage through if you show the second ticket (on the same airline/alliance). I couldn't find any information regarding Aeroflot but many airlines do list these guidelines for separate tickets on their website.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you do not need to check-out, recheck-in your luggage.

I traveled from Austria over Moscow to Bangkok with AEROFLOT and vice versa and I did not need to look after my luggage.

In my case when traveling back from Bangkok over Moscow, AEROFLOT forgot my luggage in Moscow. I filled out some forms in Vienna and got my luggage 1-3 (I can't remember) days after I have landed.

Consider staying some days in the destination city (or in near the city) before traveling further, just in case to be sure.

Comment: My booking will be on two different tickets and two different aeroflot carrier!

Comment: @Imso1987  This detail should be in the question.  But there are no 2 different carriers for Aeroflot.